# Does IBM Websphere Liberty support OSGI bundle with EJB?

Tags: websphere-liberty

I checked the IBM knowledge center, the websphere support a EJB application inside a OSGI bundle, I am not sure if Liberty also support it so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this documentation page, EJB applications in OSGi bundles are not support on WebSphere Liberty:

IBM doc: [Enterprise OSGi programming model support](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support_osgi.html)